# How many DeLoreans existed at the same time?

Tags: back-to-the-future

How many copies of the DeLorean time machine co-existed in the Back to the Future series?

Comment: Just the one?  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @GetSet You're not thinking fourth-dimensionally.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At some point in 1955, there were 4 of them. I put them in the timeline of the DeLorean.

1. The one Marty used in the first Back to the Future.
2. The one the old Biff used to give the young Biff the almanac.
3. The one Marty used in the Second Back to the Future to fix the alternate timeline.
4. The one hidden by Doc in 1885 and fixed by them later.

So, the travel is

- from 1985 Marty goes to **1955** and goes back to 1985
- from 1985 Marty goes to 2015
- from 2015 Biff  goes to **1955** then back to 2015
- from 2015 Marty goes to Alternate-1985 then to **1955**
- from 1955 Doc goes to 1885 and leaves it there until it was retrieved by Marty in **1955**
- from 1955 Marty goes to 1885 and finally to 1985

As indicated by [NominSim's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17810/how-many-deloreans-existed-at-the-same-time?newsletter=1&nlcode=25369%7C83af#comment33176_17811) the timeline, from [Mystic Alpha](https://www.deviantart.com/mysticalpha/art/Back-to-the-Future-Timeline-162530828) on deviantArt, illustrates where people and the DeLorean are throughout the trilogy.

Comment: But they were all the same DeLorean.

Comment: haven't watched 2 in a while...Did Marty return to 1955 before Old Biff's return?  If he returned after old Biff left, there would only have been 3 concurrent DeLoreans (twice).

Comment: @Jeff: No, Second Marty actually hears Old Biff talking (maybe he even sees him, don't remember that).

Comment: @Jeff I haven't watched it in a while either, but I believe that Marty listens to Old Biff giving Young Biff the almanac. (I thought the same as you originally)

Comment: @Xantec They were the same car on four different timelines.

Comment: [This](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/120/1/9/Back_to_the_Future_Timeline_by_mysticalpha.jpg) is a really cool timeline of Back to the Future.

Comment: @GabeWillard That depends on your point of view. From the DeLorean's position it was all one straight timeline.

Comment: I believe there were even more in [the video game](http://www.telltalegames.com/bttf) *(which extends the storyline, written by the same writer)*.

Comment: In the version of 1955 we saw in part II, there wouldn't have been a DeLorean hidden in the Delgado mine (at least not until Doc jumped back to 1885, at which point it probably appeared there via the ripple effect)--in BTTF each trip through time changes the timeline. There would have been a "later" version of the timeline in which Marty and Doc arrive in 1955 to recover the almanac and there is a Delorean in 1885 along with the 3 others you mention, but that wasn't the version of the timeline we saw onscreen.